# my android process app is killed

Tags: android

my app is always killed when you do anything with the phone. it doesn't work in background. how can i resolve this problem please.
i don't have great skills in coding, so if you can write the exact code, i will be very gratefull.

i think the problem may be here in this lines of code :

```
@Override
public void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    finish();
    System.runFinalizersOnExit(true);
    System.exit(0);
    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
}`
```

Comment: Delete that `onStop()` method.

Answer (score 0):

remove

```
finish();
System.runFinalizersOnExit(true);
System.exit(0);
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```